# Access WP files on "server 1", from "server 2" - using wp-load on an external website

Tags: php, functions, security

My setup consists of a "members area" which is set aside from my Wordpress install. This members area is written in PHP.
Until now, ive been using the following code in a PHP file to pull in the WP Blog Header file, before querying and pulling in posts

```
<?php require('/var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php');?>
```

However due to various reasons, i've split the Wordpress install and said members area, onto seperate VPS'.

I am curious to know what I need to do, in order to resume pulling the Wordpress posts in by the same method, now that the wordpress and other portion of my website are on two servers.

Whilst RSS would be probably the most efficient solution im guessing, is there a secure way of carrying out accessing the wordpress externally? Guessing I need to authenticate somehow

Comment: Have you checked the WordPress [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options

- file sharing, wherein the two servers can access some of the same files. The details vary according to the VPS technology used -- talk to your webhost. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/369080/is-it-possible-to-share-files-between-multiple-vps
- file syncing, wherein the two servers have separate copies of the files, but the copies are kept in sync. Here I'd probably use `git` instead of RSS.